# Is render on controller the same than in views? how to call "view" render from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a very simple js logic to implement when doing ajax request, so I've a `respond_to` block and I would like to specify the reply for js inline, so I tried to do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render js: "$('ul#slides').append('#{j(render @slide)}');" }
end
```

The problem is that this is throwing a doublicate render error, (as I have render inside a render), but, how this work if I put that piece of code in a view? how I can call the "view" render on a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey let use [render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) method to complete this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js do
    slide_html = render_to_string(partial: @slide)
    render js: "$('ul#slides').append('#{slide_html}');" }
  end
end
```